# How to select a array of rows from db and update them with another array of data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm developing a trading card game in unity and need some help with the PHP and MySQL side of things.

My database structure is something like this. This is set up when the player registers. Each player has 60 rows inside of player_deck because the decks limit is 60.

```
players
player_id/email/password/username


player_deck
player_id/card_id/card_amount
```

I'm trying to update these rows when the player saves the deck. From Unitys end I'm calling a URL that looks something like this.

```
"localhost/saveplayerdata/saveplayerdeck.php?playerid=&deckcardids=&deckcardamounts="
```

The PHP page stores the `deckcardids` and `deckcardamounts` into two arrays.

Now here is where I'm stuck. I need to get all the rows that belong to that player and update them with our data sent from Unity.

This is what I have so far. I'm able to select the rows I need but how would I go about updating them with the data in my arrays? Thanks for reading.

**EDIT:** Added my query to update. This updates all the rows. I need it to only update the current row that being looped through with the index that `deckCardIds` is at. I know my update query is wrong but I'm not sure of the correct syntax to use so that I'm only effecting the row I'm on.

```
<?php

$playerId = $_GET['playerid'];

$playerDeckCardIds = $_GET['deckcardids'];
$playerDeckCardAmounts = $_GET['deckcardamounts'];

$deckCardIds = explode(" ", $playerDeckCardIds);
array_pop($deckCardIds);
$deckCardAmounts = explode(" ", $playerDeckCardAmounts);
array_pop($deckCardAmounts);

//This is the new array of cardIds sent from Unity
//foreach ($deckCardIds as $value) 
//{
//echo "Deck Card Id $value <br>";

//}
//This is the new array of cardAmounts sent from Unity
// foreach ($deckCardAmounts as $value) 
//{
//echo "Deck Card Amount $value <br>";

//}

try
{
    #Connect to the db
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tcg', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT card_id, card_amount FROM player_deck WHERE player_id = :player_id');
    $stmt->execute(array('player_id' => $playerId));

    $r = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $i = 0;
    #If we have a result
    if (count($r))
    {
        foreach ($r as $row)
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE player_deck SET card_id = :card_id WHERE player_id = :player_id');
            $stmt->bindParam(':player_id', $playerId);

            $stmt->bindParam(':card_id', $deckCardIds[$i]);

            $stmt->execute();
            $i ++;
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Where is your update query?

Comment: @mkaatman Sorry updated my above question.